# Einstein's relation and osmotic pressure

Tags: diffusion

How can I derive the Einstein's relation $D=k_{b}TB$, where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient and B is the mobility coefficient, from the concept of osmotic pressure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two phenomena present

- *diffusion*, which happens due to inhomogeneity in concentration. Particles "want to" go from areas of higher concentration to the lower ones. One can write this in the form of diffusion current 
  $$J_{diff}(x) = - D \nabla \rho(x)$$
  where $\rho(x)$ is the concentration. This expression is known as [Fick's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Fick.27s_First_Law) but it's actually just the standard linear response to inhomogeneities.
- *drift*, which is the terminal velocity particles attain due to presence of some force. E.g. the drift one can observe for balls falling in viscous liquid. One can write 
  $$J_{drift} = \rho(x) v(x) = \rho(x) B F(x) = -B \rho(x) \nabla U(x)$$

From the requirement of equilibrium we have that $J_{diff} + J_{drift} = 0$ and from Boltzmann statistics we can obtain the concentration $\rho(x) \sim \exp(-{U(x) \over k_B T})$.
Putting it all together we get
$$0 = - D \nabla \rho(x) - B \rho(x) \nabla U(x) = - \nabla U(x) \rho(x) (-{D \over k_B T} + B)$$
and we can see the required relation in the last term.